# Detect electronic circuit elements based on images

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to detect elements from an electonic circuit based on binary images. Therefore I have to separate it into parts. Each part should describe one element, e.g. a resistor or a capacity. I also want to detect branchpoints, where multiple line (or multiple elements) are connected.

The following picture shows an example circuit, which contains two resistors and two branch-points: Example Circuit with two resistors:

[image: img].

Thats what I want my program to detect automatically.

I already implemented an algorithm which is able to detect line segments and branchpoints, when the input-image contains lines with 1px linewidth.

The problem is transforming an image into this 1px linemodel. Some like this:

[image: expected result]

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance!
Niklas

Answer (score 0):

In Matlab you can use the following code

```
% Read image
I = double(imread('circit.png'));
I = I(:,:,1);

% Run thining opreation
IThin = bwmorph(~I,'thin',Inf);

% Show image
imshow(IThin)
```

And the resulted image is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Thats what I already tried, but as you can see, the lines are not straight forward and at the branch point, the lines are round. How can I realize the expected result I showed in the initial post with Matlab?